# Symfony2/Twig duplicate stylesheets

Tags: symfony, twig, stylesheet

i have in my base.html.twig this part of code:

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/study/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/study/css/style.css') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/study/css/boilerplate.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css')}}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

And Symfony2/Twig in the webpage code generate:

```
<link href="/bundles/study/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bundles/study/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Why Twig generate 6 calls to the same links?

I can propvide any information about the code, if i quit

'{% stylesheets 'bundles/study/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}' and '{% endstylesheets %}'

All work normally (I think) but i need understand why Twig create 6 times the same lines

Answer (score 3):

When you type :

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/study/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
```

You tell Twig to include all (*) files in `bundles/study/css`.
For each file found, you will have the content between `stylesheets` and `endstylesheets`, so basically, if you have 6 file, you will have 6 times you content...

You should read [this article about Symfony2 & Assetic](http://symfony.com/en/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html).